# I am not able to fetch data from MySQL Database in Nodejs bot file

Tags: node.js

Please help me out in fetching data from database

```
app.get('/', function(_req, resp)
{
    console.log("enter into db");
    mysqlconnection.query(`SELECT Description FROM Chatbot `, function(error, rows, fields)
    { 
        if(!!error) 
        {
            console.log(`Error in the query`);
        } 
        else 
        {
            console.log(`Successful query`);
            console.log(rows);
            //resp.send(rows);
        }
    });
    app.listen(3978);
})
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: How to write a query when I have to n no. of events in my table and I wanted to fetch data accordingly.....I have tested the query for one event : SELECT Description FROM Chatbot WHERE name= 'Hackathon'; but not able to get how to put the query if have 16 events